# make ignores -std=c99 flag when compiling and linking a C program

Tags: c, compilation, makefile

I've tried to get my makefile to compile a file that requires `-std=c99` to run. In this case, its to get a "for-loop" through.

This is my code, (its been used "tab" before "$(CC)" ):

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c -std=c99

...

Download.o : Download.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Download.c
```

Download.c contains methods used to download elements from the web

#### Error message

```
$ make
gcc -c -std=c99 Download.c
gcc Download.c -o Program
Download.c: In function ‘downloadImageparts’:
Download.c:11:2: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
Download.c:11:2: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
Download.c:13:3: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
make: *** [comp] Error 1
```

#### Attemt to debug

If I run `gcc -c -std=c99 Download.c` in terminal it works fine.

This problems appears when run in Linux.

**SOLVED:**

I created a dummy project to show my lecturer, in an attempt to solve my problem. In the dummy project all works fine with the code described. For some reason my code works on place but not in the other. If someone reading this having the same problem as me and would like to see an example project. let me know and I'll write the code here. Thanks

Comment: Which version of `make` are you using?

Comment: The make prints what command it executes. If you didn't see the command you have expected then you could have asked why you don't see it rather than asking about unrelated for loops and leaving people guessing...

Comment: not sure what version of make Im using. sorry. just using an ubuntu distrubution, and the make syntax in my program folder

Comment: Post the output of `make`: what command does it print that causes the error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong rule.  `Download.c` is actually compiling fine, but the linking stage is wrong.

```
$ make
gcc -c -std=c99 Download.c  # Compile
gcc Download.c -o Program   # Link
```

Fix the make rule that links the program.  It should probably look something like this:

```
Program: a.o b.o c.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

While you're at it, I suggest a more complete Makefile will look something like this:

```
all: Program
clean:
    rm -f Program *.o
.PHONY: all clean

# -c is implicit, you don't need it (it *shouldn't* be there)
# CC is also implicit, you don't need it
CFLAGS := -std=c99 -g -Wall -Wextra

Program: a.o b.o c.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

# Make will automatically generate the necessary commands
# You just need to name which headers each file depends on
# (You can make the dependencies automatic but this is simpler)
a.o: a.c header.h
b.o: b.c header.h header2.h
c.o: c.c header.h
```

#### Examples of how to do it wrong

Linker flags are actually fairly touchy!  Be sure to type in the line above exactly as I have written it, and don't assume that what you've written is equivalent.  Here are some examples of *slightly* different commands that are wrong and **should not be used:**

```
# WRONG: program must depend on *.o files, NOT *.c files
Program: a.c b.c c.c
    $(CC) ...

# WRONG: -c should not be in CFLAGS
CFLAGS := -c -std=c99

Program: a.o b.o c.o
    # WRONG: $(CFLAGS) should not be here
    # you are NOT compiling, so they do not belong here
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

    # WRONG: $(LIBS) MUST come at the end
    # otherwise linker may fail to find symbols
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LIBS) $^

    # WRONG: do not list *.o files, use $^ instead
    # otherwise it is easy to get typos here
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ a.o b.o c.o $(LIBS)

    # WRONG: $(LDFLAGS) must be at the beginning
    # it only applies to what comes after, so you
    # MUST put it at the beginning
    $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS)

    # WRONG: -c flag disables linking
    # but we are trying to link!
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

    # WRONG: use $(CC), not gcc
    # Don't sabotage your ability to "make CC=clang" or "make CC=gcc-4.7"
    gcc $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

    # WRONG: ld does not include libc by default!
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

Comment: afaik: "$@" = is the name of the "command", wich is "Program"; "$^" = is the .o files used in the command, a.o b.o c.o ; and $(LIBS) are just a variable for the libraries, like -lm; This will then generate something like: "cc -c -sdt=c99 a.c b.c c.c -o Program a.o b.o c.o"; If Im correct, then this did not help me :( still getting the same error.

Comment: @BlazingMist: No, that's wrong.  (1) There should be no `*.c` files in the command.  Don't add `*.c` files as dependencies, **only** add `*.o` files as dependencies.  Use `$^` and don't type it in yourself.  (2) There should be no `-c` flag.  You should not have `-c` in your `CFLAGS`, and `CFLAGS` should not be in your linker command.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same results if I use spaces instead of tabs inside the makefile, and the output of `make` shows that the rule isn't being used:

```
$ make
cc    -c -o Download.o Download.c
Download.c: In function ‘main’:
Download.c:4:3: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
Download.c:4:3: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
make: *** [Download.o] Error 1
```

Try a <kbd>tab</kbd> before the line starting with `gcc`.

---

After seeing the update to the original question:

```
$ make
gcc -c -std=c99 Download.c
gcc Download.c -o Program
```

The first (compile) line shows no errors.
It's the second line, which *re-compiles* `Download.c`, that fails.
I think you want to link the `.o` files to create the executable `Program` here, as Dietrich Epp [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328521/29157).